# SSRS change data source at runtime

Tags: reporting-services

I have build reports on SSRS the I am extracting same report from multiple databases
I made shared `data Source` but my problem is about how to change data source reference programmatically at runtime?

like make dropdown list that user can choose the `data source` then view report simply

thanks

Comment: As far as I know you cannot swap data sources programmatically. However, you **can** create an embedded (not shared) data source in your report and make that dynamic. See this answer I posted a few years ago it should help. If it dose not help, edit your question and explain exactly what parts of the datasource should change. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65213887

Comment: @AlanSchofield Thanks, but I do not want to use embedded data source because I have around 50 reports and if I changed user or locked I have to change the data source user name and password on all these reports